# Dividing a dictionary in groups by their values

Tags: c#, dictionary, split, extract

I have a `Dictionary<string, int>` which contains components as `string` and positions as `int`. Now I want to divide the dictionary into four groups and save each group in a separate dictionary.

> group 1 = all positions 1 - 32
>   group 2 = all positions 33 -64
>   group 3 = all positions 101 - 132
>   group 4 = all positions 133 - 164

This is what I have at the moment.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = compPos;
```

After filling the dictionary I ordered the dictionary like this.

```
var items = from pair in dictionary
            orderby pair.Value ascending
            select pair;
```

I was thinking about using for loops to get all the components and positions where value <= 32 etc. But so far this is the only way I think it might be possible.

Comment: You could group by the output of a function that maps the position (`.Value`) to the relevant group (groups 1 through 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ToDictionary()` method to create a new dictionary:

```
var newDictionary = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value < 32).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

edit: 
Add d=> to the second argument

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

dictionary.Add("a", 1);
dictionary.Add("b", 2);
dictionary.Add("c", 34);
dictionary.Add("d", 35);
dictionary.Add("e", 105);
dictionary.Add("f", 106);
dictionary.Add("g", 140);
dictionary.Add("h", 141);

var items = from pair in dictionary
            orderby pair.Value ascending
            select pair;

var list_1_32 = items.Where(v => v.Value >= 1 && v.Value <= 32)
                .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
var list_33_64 = items.Where(v => v.Value >= 33 && v.Value <= 64)
                 .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
var list_101_132 = items.Where(v => v.Value >= 101 && v.Value <= 132)
                   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
var list_133_164 = items.Where(v => v.Value >= 133 && v.Value <= 164)
                   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);

Action<Dictionary<string, int>> print = instance =>
{
  foreach ( var item in instance )
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
};

print(list_1_32);
Console.WriteLine();
print(list_33_64);
Console.WriteLine();
print(list_101_132);
Console.WriteLine();
print(list_133_164);
```

Output:

```
a: 1
b: 2

c: 34
d: 35

e: 105
f: 106

g: 140
h: 141
```